# extendscript: get folders of Project

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

I want to read all subfolders of my current Project. Because my Project is using images from the Footage-Folder i need all the sub-Folders of it.

For now i only have the current Path of my project:

```
 var projectPath=app.project.file.path;
```

Comment: Did you try to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project path you get with:

```
app.project.file.parent
```

And all the recursive folders you get with:

```
function getFoldersRecursive(folder) {
    var
        files = folder.getFiles(),
        editFolders = [],
        folder;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        folder = files[i];
        if (folder instanceof Folder) {
            editFolders.push(folder);
            editFolders = editFolders.concat(getFoldersRecursive(folder));
        }
    }
    return editFolders;
}

var projectFolder = app.project.file.parent;
var allFolders = getFoldersRecursive(projectFolder);
```